# Сколько доступно оперативной памяти?

Tags: windows, виртуальная-память

Файл подкачки был выставлен в ноль. В компьютере имеется 16 Gb оперативной памяти. По информации системы физической памяти доступно 8,77 Gb из 16 Gb. В то время как виртуальной памяти доступно 4,77 Gb из 16 Gb. Так сколько оперативной памяти доступно для использования на данный момент?

Comment: Что за «информацию системы» вы смотрите? Когда я пытаюсь смотреть вкладку «Память» в «Диспетчере задач», там в принципе не существует ни термина «физической памяти доступно», ни термина «виртуальной памяти доступно». В «Мониторе ресурсов» я тоже не вижу таких терминов

Comment: В старом «Диспетчере задач» из Windows 7 я вижу пункт «Физическая память → Доступно», но вот про виртуальную память там тоже ничего нет

Comment: @andreymal Информацию смотрю в программе Mem Reduct.

Comment: Если заглянуть в [исходики программы Mem Reduct](https://github.com/henrypp/memreduct/blob/e6acf72b2d4c8118ac074fc23c2b0f36c30fb253/src/main.c#L181), то там видно, что она берёт информацию из [MEMORYSTATUSEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/ns-sysinfoapi-memorystatusex), так что можно начать курить маны отсюда